# Ceylon metamodel

Tags: reflection, metamodel, ceylon

I am studying Ceylon and have question about it metamodel. I want to create some create some base class 'DataContainer' which allow to instantiate immutable classes with build-in equals-hash implementation:
e.g. Identifier(125, "ab") == Identifier(125, "ab")
So base class should collect all shared non-variable values and use this information in 'hash' an 'equals' methods.
I have wrote this code:

```ceylon
shared abstract class DataContainer(ClassDeclaration declaration) {
    value members = {
        for (i in declaration.memberDeclarations<ValueDeclaration>())
            if (!i.variable, i.name != "hash", i.name != "string") i
    };
    variable Integer? hashCode = null;

    shared actual Boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (is DataContainer that) {
            for (item in members) {
                value thisMember = item.memberGet(this);
                value thatMember = item.memberGet(that);
                if (exists thisMember, exists thatMember) {
                    if (thisMember != thatMember) { return false; }
                } else if (thisMember exists != thatMember exists) { return false; }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    shared actual Integer hash => hashCode else (hashCode = calculateHash());

    Integer calculateHash() {
        variable value result = 0;
        for(i in members) {
            if (exists member = i.memberGet(this)) {
                result = result.xor(member.hash);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Identifier(shared Integer? id, shared String? name) extends DataContainer(`class`) {}
```

The Identifier class is the client of DataContainer. I like this solution in whole but I have to pass 'class' into the super class constructor because if I use 'class' inside DataContainer it doesn't see any members of subclass.
How can I obtain actual list of extended class's members in base class methods?
Something like 'this' doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution thanks to guys from Ceylon community. The function classDeclaration(this) from ceylon.language.meta should be used instead of 'class'.

This is the final code:

```ceylon
shared abstract class DataContainer() {
    variable Integer? _hash = null;
    variable ValueDeclaration[]? _members = null;

    shared actual Boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (is DataContainer that) {
            for (i in members) {
                value thisMember = i.memberGet(this);
                value thatMember = i.memberGet(that);
                if (exists thisMember, exists thatMember) {
                    if (thisMember != thatMember) { return false; }
                } else if (thisMember exists != thatMember exists) { return false; }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    shared actual Integer hash => _hash else (_hash = calculateHash());

    ValueDeclaration[] members => _members else (_members = [
        for (i in classDeclaration(this).memberDeclarations<ValueDeclaration>())
            if (!i.variable, i.name != "string", i.name != "hash") i
    ]);

    Integer calculateHash() {
        variable Integer result = 0;
        for (i in members) {
            if (exists member = i.memberGet(this)) {
                result = result.xor(member.hash);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Identifier(shared Integer? number, shared String? name) extends DataContainer() {}
```

Comment: should DataContainer perhaps `extends Object()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Alexander's formidable answer, I took the liberty to implement a `string` function as well so you can just `print(myObj)` and it renders nicely:

```
shared default actual String string {
    value s = StringBuilder();
    s.append(type(this).declaration.name).append(" { ");
    for (i in members) {
        value m = i.memberGet(this);
        s.append(i.name).append(":");
        s.append(if(exists m) then m.string else "<null>");
    }
    return s.append(" }").string;
}
```